# file upload queue remain same after refresh?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular file upload for my project. referring the below link I have worked my project
http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/

My requirement is once I select a file or multiple file if I refresh also it should not remove from the queue.
I tried to use localstorage but its not working

Here is the code where I have used local storage.

```
uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems)
        {
            console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
            $localStorage.allfiles= addedFileItems;

        };
```

At the end I did get console but it is showing empty.

```
console.log($localStorage.allfiles);
```

Please any one can help on this will be a great help

Comment: It is not possible to do it with callback - `uploader.onAfterAddingAll()`; because it is only called after adding files, not on page refresh. The assignment to localstorage is okay, but you need to access it on ngInit() or page load.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so before starting please go through [MDN Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). It states that

> The Web Storage API provides mechanisms by which browsers can store key/value pairs, in a much more intuitive fashion than using cookies.

So localStorage can store key value pairs and as of now only string values are supported. It can not store files. So you wont be able to achieve what you are trying as you want to store file and that's not supported.

Also if you want to store objects you will have to stringify them and then store.

One suggested solution i have is you can convert your files to a bytes array and then store them and then you can handle those bytes the way you want.

Also this might help you I think thats waht you want . [Mozilla Hacks Storing Images in localStorage](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/)

Once the image is saved as data url which is base 64 encode. You just need to send the string to the server and decode it with base 64